# Coral Dev Board : Not recognized by computer/raspberry pi

Tags: tpu, google-coral

I am trying to use the Google Coral Dev Board. I am following the tutorial [Get Started with the Dev Board](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/get-started/) and I am stucked at the *Flash the board* part and precisely at the step :

```
dmesg | grep ttyUSB
```

This request returns me nothing, in fact there are no usb using the cp210x listed converter after doing *dmesg*.
I have verified the content of */etc/udev/rules.d/65-edgetpu-board.rules* and it is good.

And *lsusb* gives me :

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My user account is in the *dialout* and *plugdev* groups. And the cp210x driver is running.

I have this problem on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and on a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

Comment: Did you try to change the USB cable ?

Comment: Yes to no change

Comment: I was facing the same issue but changing the USB cable worked for me.

Comment: When you connect to the serial console port, do you see the LEDs light up as noted in the instructions? This verifies the serial converter is getting power. If not, you might try also connecting the USB-C PWR cable to see if it helps.

Comment: When I connect the board to the serial console port I get the Leds (green and orange) lighted up, as in the instructions.

Comment: I would suggest reaching out to coral-support@google.com. There may be an issue with your board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been in touch with Google-Coral re this. I have had the same problem.  Linux must have a driver for the particular USB used.  The driver is cp210x.  Just sorted this out yesterday.

Doing a lsmod should show is cp210x is on your machine.

Link shows how to do the install.

http://headstation.com/archives/instructions-installing-cp210x-serial-bridge-driver/

The driver is available from Silicon Labs and the instructions have the details.

I am still working on this.  It is evidently a known issue.  It is worth a shot. I am also suspicious of a board problem on mine as Windows cp210x drivers will not id the board.  Widows drivers are a very rapid install, That is not a definitive test and will do a Linux  make tonight.

Google-Coral has been very helpful on this.  I believe they are in Bangalore so there is a 12 hour delay in response.  I told them about your posting.

Comment: I worked on this for a while.  Thee is an excellent post on ak unubutu

Comment: the drivers are part of Ubuntu 16 but have to be loaded.   The link explains how.  We tried the boards on Ubuntu 19 and they wee recognized with no loading necessary.  My version of 18 required loading the drivers.   Sorry re multiple comments I  keep hitting the return,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is related or not. Flashing the SD via serial drove me crazy and I finally  got a solution from Google support. They send me the link

https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/reflash/#flash-from-u-boot-on-an-sd-card

But the name of system image is different from the one working with serial. I don't know the difference

Comment: The image provided is just so you can boot into the sd card instead of the serial. Once you're in, you will still flash with the same mendel image!